# Scala convert Option to an Int

Tags: scala, scala-collections

I have looked at these links

http://blog.danielwellman.com/2008/03/using-scalas-op.html

http://blog.tmorris.net/scalaoption-cheat-sheet/

I have a map of [String, Integer] and when I do a map.get("X") I get an option. I would like the following.

```
val Int count = map.get(key); 
// If the key is there I would like value if it is not I want 0
```

How do I achieve this in one line? I need to do this several times. It looks a bit inefficient to write a function everytime for doing this. I am sure there is some intelligent one line quirk that I am missing but I really like to get the value into an integer in ONE line :)

Comment: If you get an Option then you have a Map[String, Option[Int]] not a Map[String, Int].

Comment: @MirkoN. No, it is because get returns Option[Value]. scala> `Map(1 -> 2).get(1)`  
`res2: Option[Int] = Some(2)`

Comment: Well, what will you do if the `Int` is not available? Depending on the answer to that, the optimal solution is different.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Just use getOrElse method:

```
val count: Int = map.getOrElse(key,0);
```

Note also, that in Scala you write type **after** name, not before.

Comment: The problem I got is the type is still Any instead of being an Integer. map.getOrElse(key,0) returns a type of Any

Answer (score 6):

@om-nom-nom (classic screen name) has the correct answer, but in the interest of providing *yet another way*™

```
val count = map.get(key) fold(0)(num => num)
```

Before in-the-know users bash me with, "Option has no fold!", [fold has been added to Option](http://groups.google.com/group/scala-language/browse_thread/thread/df911c8a8c52439d#) in *Scala 2.10*

getOrElse is of course better in the current case, but in some Some/None scenarios it may be interesting to 1-liner with fold like so (*edited complements of @Debiliski who tested against latest 2.10 snapshot*):

```
val count = map.get(k).fold(0)(dao.userlog.count(_))
```

I suppose in 2.9.2 and under we can already do:

```
val count = map get(k) map ( dao.userlog.count(_) ) getOrElse(0)
```

Which is to say, in Scala there is often more than one way to do the same thing: in the linked thread, the OP shows more than 10 alternative means to achieve Option fold ;-)

Comment: yah, I got excited too when I came across the scala-lang thread ;-) Hopefully 2.10 M3 will be released soon after Scala Days conference finishes, a lot to look forward to in Scala.Next

Comment: @virtualeyes: That would be `map.get(key).fold(0)(num => num)` in 2.10 (at least going by the current nightly).

Comment: @Debilski, right, was going with OP's approach in the scala-lang thread; there was a lot of back & forth over the order (some, none) or (none, some); looks like Paul Phillips went with (none)(some) based on his latest commit "https://github.com/scala/scala/commit/bb4935e92c". I'll edit my answer so at not mislead further ;-) thanks

Comment: "fold(0)(num => num)" is a bit annoying, "fold(0)(x)" would be wonderfully concise...

Comment: This makes no sense: `(none => 0, num => num)`. There's no value to pass in the `None` case, so folding it doesn't take a function.

Comment: @Debiliski, set that straight, but neglected to fix in the first example, corrected now...

Comment: @virtualeyes: If you want to set a single `x` in case of a `Some` (regardless of the `Some`s value), you don’t need a `fold` anyway. And if all you have is `fold(0)(x => x)` or `fold(0)(identity)`, then a `getOrElse` is more concise anyway.

Comment: indeed, for the getOrElse case. I was more pointing out (or trying to) a possible use case for fold with Option similar to folding over an Either, where one performs an operation based on the left (none) or right (some) condition; that is, vs. simply returning a default value.

Comment: *in Scala there is often more than one way to do the same thing*. That really scare me sometimes: I don't want Scala to become new Perl.

Comment: @om-nom-nom too late, Martin O wants to simplify, but the Scala train has already left the station, all aboard ;-) I would describe Scala as refined Perl with added hieroglyphic symbolism, the overmind (_++_) being one of my favorites. SBT and FP take things to an entirely different level, from the outside looking in, no wonder Scala has the "complex" stigma. A few months into learning Scala, I absolutely love it, but the beginning was chock full of WTFs

Answer (score 3):

Yet another way.

```
import scalaz._, Scalaz._

scala> val m = Map(9 -> 33)
m: scala.collection.immutable.Map[Int,Int] = Map(9 -> 33)

scala> m.get(9).orZero
res3: Int = 33

scala> m.get(8).orZero
res4: Int = 0
```

Answer (score 0):

for import scala.collection.mutable.SortedMap

```
val myMap =  SortedMap[[Integer,Integer]
val theGotten = myMap.getOrElse(aKey,0)
returned an Any   but

val myMap =  SortedMap[[Int,Int]
val theGotten = myMap.getOrElse(aKey,0)
returns an Int
```